# ReactJs validation with no form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Hi I am wondering if I can make a validation that is not based on a user input but based on an object derived from somewhere else. For example I have an object like this:

```
userDetails{
  "id":1,
  "surname":"Wood",
  "firstName":"Victor"
}
```

and I have a Yup validation like this

```
export const userDetailValidation= Yup.object().shape({
  surname: Yup.string().
         .required("This field is required.")
         .max(50, "Maximum character is 50.")
  firstName: Yup.string().
         .required("This field is required.")
         .max(50, "Maximum character is 50.")
});
```

What can I do so that I can validate the object that I have based on that Yup Validation?

Comment: `Yup is a schema builder for runtime value parsing and validation.` There is nothing said about this being specifically for use with html forms.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the Yup validation to validate your object. You can use the `.validate()` method to check if the object meets the validation requirements. For example:

```
const isValid = userDetailValidation.validate(userDetails, {abortEarly: false});
```

If the validation passes, isValid will be true. Otherwise, it will be false.